# IE 9 Input element padding issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've seen this topic come up several times: You wanna create a search-box that has a nice icon in it's right (or left) corner, that looks like it's part of the text-box but text doesn't get written under/over it, like so:

[image] (from chrome)

Usually what people do is something like this:

```
<div class="searchWrapper">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="searchIcon"></div>
</div>
```

And there are several posts here on Stack Overflow dealing with making this work on IE such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765411/html-ie-right-padding-in-input-text-box) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607198/padding-a-text-input-in-ie-possible).

But I'm trying a different approach - I don't wanna wrap my textbox if I don't have to, and rather have it as a style applied to the `<INPUT>` itself.

I've come up with this piece of CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/motig/bvV46/4/ which works on Chrome and (after some tweaking) on IE10:

[image]

Great, but I need to support IE 9 as well (but no lower than that). This does not work on IE 9 though:

[image]

due to IE 9 (and below) ignoring the `padding` on text-boxes. Even if I set `line-height`, it becomes quirky and has the text jump back the `25px` only when it reaches the text-box's edge.

The only workaround I can think of is using a *condcom* to wrap the text-box for IE 8 only. But that's as ugly as wrapping it in the first place. Are the any other solutions?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit @cimmanon, you missed one though. ;)